# compare two files and print differences in Java

Tags: java

I tried to compare two files and print out the differences between them. However, my code only print the last sentence which is where the second difference in each file.

```
/*
-------------------------------
data1:
This file has a great deal of
text in it which needs to 

be processed.
-------------------------------
data2:
This file has a grate deal of 
text in it which needs to 

bee procesed.
-------------------------------
*/

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CompareTwoFiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String first = "", second = "";
        String firstName = "", secondName = "";

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a first file name: ");
        firstName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter a second file name: ");
        secondName = input.nextLine();

        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(new File(firstName));//read first file
        while (input1.hasNextLine()) {
            first = input1.nextLine();
        }

        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(new File(secondName));//read second file
        while (input2.hasNextLine()) {
            second = input2.nextLine();
        }

        if (!first.equals(second)) {
            System.out.println("Differences found: " + "\n" + first + '\n' + second);
        }
    }
}

/*
output:
Enter a first file name: data1.txt
Enter a second file name: data2.txt
Differences found: 
be processed.
bee procesed.
*/
```

Comment: well, you only compare the last sentence.

Comment: In your `while` loops the variables `first` and `second` are always getting overwriten. So finally both variables are storing the last line of the two files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should be

```
Scanner input1 = new Scanner(new File(firstName));//read first file
Scanner input2 = new Scanner(new File(secondName));//read second file

while(input1.hasNextLine() && input2.hasNextLine()){
    first = input1.nextLine();   
    second = input2.nextLine(); 

    if(!first.equals(second)){
        System.out.println("Differences found: "+"\n"+first+'\n'+second);
    }
}

// optionally handle any remaining lines if the line count differs
```

Previously you only compared one time, the very last line. But you need to compare after each line you read.